# ListTile onLongPress Event Not working Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listtile

I encountered weird issue while creating a learning Todo App. I implemented TaskList Class and TaskTile class as below.

**TaskList Class as below**

```
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:todoey/Models/taskdata.dart';
import 'package:todoey/widgets/task_tile.dart';

class TasksList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<TasksList> createState() => _TasksListState();
}

class _TasksListState extends State<TasksList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<TaskData>(builder: (context, taskData, child) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final task = taskData.taskList[index];
          return TaskTile(
            longPressCallBack: () {
              taskData.deleteTask(task);
            },
            name: task.name,
            isChecked: task.isDone,
            checkBoxCallBack: (newValue) {
              taskData.updateTask(task);
            },
          );
        },
        itemCount: taskData.taskList.length,
      );
    });
  }
}
```

**TaskTile Class as below**

```
class TaskTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool? isChecked;
  final String name;
  final Function checkBoxCallBack;
  final Function longPressCallBack;

  TaskTile(
      {required this.name,
      this.isChecked,
      required this.checkBoxCallBack,
      required this.longPressCallBack});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        name,
        style: TextStyle(
          decoration: isChecked! ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : null,
        ),
      ),
      trailing: Checkbox(
        fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.lightBlueAccent),
        checkColor: Colors.white,
        value: isChecked!,
        onChanged: (newValue) {
          checkBoxCallBack(newValue);
        },
      ),
      onLongPress: () => longPressCallBack,
    );
  }
}
```

Now the problem is it doesn't call longPressCallBack of parent class i.e. TaskList class. I debugged and it calls onLongPress of TaskTile class but not calling callback to it's parent class and that is why deleteTask not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this line `onLongPress: () => longPressCallBack,` on your `TaskTile` class. Here you are just invoking `longPressCallBack` **closure reference** instead of executing the closure function.

Solution:

Change that line to this :  `onLongPress: () => longPressCallBack(),` or try directly passing function refrence to `onLongPress` property of `ListTile` like this  `onLongPress: longPressCallBack,`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `VoidCallback` instead, look at the following sample code:

```
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  String greeting = "Hello World!";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(
          greeting,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
        ),
        TestButton(
          onClickCallback: () {
            setState(() {
              greeting = "Hello Test!";
            });
            
          }
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class TestButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback onClickCallback;
  
  const TestButton( {required this.onClickCallback});
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      child: const Text("TestButton"),
      onPressed: onClickCallback,
    );
      
  }
}
```